# How to send value to _popen?

Tags: popen

I have a problem here. I need to send some value to 'text1 and 'text2'. For example,

text1 =

...and this code below will refer to those values..

```
FILE  *child = _popen("java -jar c:\\simmetrics.jar text1 text2 > c:\\test.txt", "r");
```

How can achieve it. I have done many ways, and it keep on giving me pointer errors.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection is accomplished by the shell, not by the execution or piping mechanism. Since popen gives you a FILE* object on which you can read from the program's standard output, you should simply read from the result file and write that result to a FILE* that you construct with [fopen](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html)("test.txt","w"). Also, you should be aware that the IEEE Std. 1003.1 "POSIX" function is [popen](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html), the _popen business is a MSFT thing.